# 500 internal server error after GAE Deployment

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am building my new project. When I was deploying my project in to Google App Engine, sometimes for all the ajax calls 500 internal server error is coming. If I deploy the same version 2 to 3 times then that error will not occur. Project will run with out any errors. What is the reason that is occurring this error?

LOGS::

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.acti.service.TranscriptServiceHelper.transcriptsdataNew(TranscriptServiceHelper.java:89)
    at com.acti.controller.AdminQueueGae.getTransctriptFromGAENEW(AdminQueueGae.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:774)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1186)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:803)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1086)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:914)
    at com.acti.util.JdoUtil.<clinit>(JdoUtil.java:16)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-f5af4d782f20b522(Request.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1951)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1159)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/exceptions/NucleusFatalUserException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-f5af4d782f20b522(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2479)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2841)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:269)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:571)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:300)
    at org.datanucleus.store.FederationManager.initialiseStoreManager(FederationManager.java:168)
    at org.datanucleus.store.FederationManager.<init>(FederationManager.java:70)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.initialiseStoreManager(ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:526)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:127)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusFatalUserException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-f5af4d782f20b522(Request.java)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: first you need to know what is the error, check the logs to see why your request getting 500

Comment: check the logs from the appengine Logs page and paste the error logs in the question.

Comment: @marcadian can you once look at the logs